# 18.04 -> 22.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel

I did an upgrade of 18.04LTS -> 22.04LTS using the software updater. After rebooting the system does not boot proper. Below the output (manual re-entered from the other machine, so maybe a type)

```
Call Trace:
<TASK>
show_stack+0x52/0x5c
dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/=x63
dump_stack+0x10/0x16
panic+0x149/0x321
mount_block_root+0x144/0x1dd
mount_root0x10c/=x11c
prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x191
kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x1b5
? rest_init+0x100/+x100
kernel_init+0x1b/0x150
?rest_init+0x100/0x100
ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
</TASK>
Kernel Offset: 0x1da00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff81000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syyncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0.0) ]---
```

I've an (old) Lenovo W540, 8core, 2.7GHz, 32Gb RAM

I tried to salvage with a boot from USB (Linux 22.04 Desktop), but since I did not see the original files I decided against installing

Anyone suggestions? As long as I get my data off it's all fine by me (so using the OS from USB, but with access to the data under )

Thanks,

Andreas

Comment: There is no upgrade path from 18.04 to 22.04.

Comment: ouch. Remains the problem, how do I get past the problem (or, how do I get to my files)

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and mount your disk. It is unclear why you "did not see the original files". It is unclear what you did to upgrade, etc.

Comment: I did the upgrade via the software updater (the one asking "there is an upgrade available"), and I went from 18.04 -> 22.10. I do not recall making the 18:04 -> 20.x in between.

Comment: I also did a boot from USB (22.10, Desktop version), but I did not see only the default set of files that you see when installing from scratch.
If I understand you correctly you suggest to mount the “old” disk (the one on the machine, not the USB drive). Not being an OS wizard, how do I do that?

Comment: Start Files and click on the disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Karel, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately not applicable to my case, I even can't get the machine booted

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the steps the OP followed but to anyone trying to update from 18.04 to 22.04 these steps worked for me on two systems (Intel 4790 and Ryzen 2400G):

You need to do a release upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and then from 20.04 to 22.04

Step by step:

1. tappend these to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (this is an important step that fixes the OP question, without this you cannot upgrade packages, and dist-upgrade, and without that you cannot do the releas upgrade):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
```

2. Now on the following steps you would be needing to answer with OK and y on a few questions so make sure you look once in a while on your display, you would be needing a few restarts and it takes anywhere from half an hour to 1-2 hours, update the package list:

   sudo apt update

now upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

followed by dist upgrade

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

then remove all packages from your system by entering the following command (this is optional):

sudo apt autoremove

install the update-manager-core  package by running the following command, in case you don't have it already:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

after that, you cand run the release upgrade utility. To do this by the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

after this is ready you have 20.04, once you have 20.04 (check with `lsb_release -a`) run one more time:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

after this is ready you should have 22.04

Comment: All, thank you for your advice. I did not try all suggested methods; I used brute force. I ran  Ubuntu from a USB stick, and made a backup of all data. I then installed Ubuntu 22.04. It solved the problem. As said, not elegant, but it did the trick

Comment: @user9165100 that is not quite an upgrade